# Replace fractions with fractions regular expressions, numbers with numbers regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've the following regular expressions that I want to run on the example input, to replace both numbers and fractions (I need to multiply them by a number that the user will choose):

```
numbersRegex = /[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?/g;
fractionsRegex = /((\d+)\/(\d+))/g;
```

The numbersRegex needs to run on lines containing numbers only (I marked them in the example input underneath using numbersRegex).

The fractionsRegex needs to run on lines containing fractions only (I marked them in the example input underneath using fractionsRegex).

I need them to be two different ones as the multiplication method is different, so I would like to run str.replace two times, one to multiply all fractions and the other to multiply all numbers.

Here is the example input:

```
1 1/2 oz. white rum (fractionsRegex)
1/2 lime, cut in 4 wedges (fractionsRegex)
10 mint leaves, fresh (numbersRegex)
2 tbsp. white sugar (numbersRegex)
1 cup ice cubes (numbersRegex)
1/2 cup club soda (fractionsRegex)
```

Is that possible?

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

This is the function I'm currently using (it needs to be cleaned up and I'm sure it can also be optimised):

```
function _increaseServings(target, initialServings, newServings) {
    target.html(originalIngredientsHTML);

    target.find('li').each(function(i) {
        var currentLine = $(this).text();
        var importantPart = currentLine.split(',');

        var fractionsRegex = importantPart[0].match(/((\d+)\/(\d+))/g);
        var lineHiddenFractions = importantPart[0] != null ? importantPart[0].replace(/([0-9]{1,})([\/]{1})([0-9]{1,})/g, "") : "";
        var numbersRegex = lineHiddenFractions.match(/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)/g);

        var result = {};
        var strToReplace = '';

        if (fractionsRegex == null && numbersRegex == null) return;

        if (fractionsRegex !== null && fractionsRegex.length > 0) {
            result.fraction = fractionsRegex[0];

            strToReplace = result.fraction;
        }

        if (numbersRegex !== null && numbersRegex.length > 0) {
            result.number = parseInt(numbersRegex[0]);

            if(result.fraction) {
                strToReplace = result.number + ' ' + strToReplace;
            } else {
                strToReplace = result.number;
            }   
        }

        if(result.fraction) {
            var fraction = result.fraction.split('/');
            if(result.number && result.fraction) {
                result.decimal = parseInt(result.number) + parseInt(fraction[0]) / parseInt(fraction[1]);
            } else {
                result.decimal = parseInt(fraction[0]) / parseInt(fraction[1]);                
            }
        } else {
            result.decimal = parseInt(result.number);
        }

        result.stringToReplace = strToReplace;

        var newValue = result.decimal * (newServings / initialServings);

        if(newValue % 1 != 0) {
            var values = String(newValue).split('.');

            var checkValue = String(values[1]).slice(0,1);
            var integerPart = Math.floor(newValue);

            if(checkValue == 2) {
                // 25
                newValue = integerPart + ' 1/4';
            } else if(checkValue == 3) {
                // 33
                newValue = integerPart + ' 1/3';
            } else if(checkValue == 5) {
                // 50
                newValue = integerPart + ' 1/2';
            } else if(checkValue == 6) {
                // 66
                newValue = integerPart + ' 2/3';
            } else if(checkValue == 7) {
                // 75
                newValue = integerPart + ' 3/4';
            }

            if(integerPart == 0) newValue = newValue.slice(2, newValue.length);
        }

        currentLine = currentLine.replace(strToReplace, newValue);

        $(this).text(currentLine);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't really get your question. Do you want to determine if the string contains a fraction or a number to decide which of the regexps you're gonna use on it? If so, test with the fraction regexp first whether the string contains a fraction. If the test fails, use the number regexp. If that doesn't help, please clarify your question. :)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Do you want **1** regexp that will extract the fractions from fraction lines and number from lines with no fractions?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain better

Comment: You *say* containing *only* numbers or *only* fractions, but `line 2` has both a fraction and a number.

Comment: In that case I just care about multiplying the fraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, javascript regular expressions don't support negative lookbehinds, so you will get false positives on your fraction numbers when you are looking for just numbers.  There's no way to say something like...

```
"/(?<!\/)([0-9])/"
```

...in javascript, so you will end up picking up some of the digits from the fraction.

You have to fake out the results with something like this:

Assuming your text is terminated with \n just for testing purposes:

```
var t = "1 1/2 oz. white rum (fractionsRegex)\n1/2 lime, cut in 4 wedges (fractionsRegex)\n10 mint leaves, fresh (numbersRegex)\n2 tbsp. white sugar (numbersRegex)\n1 cup ice cubes (numbersRegex)\n1/2 cup club soda (fractionsRegex)";
var ary = t.split("\n");

for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    var fractionsRegex = ary[i].match(/((\d+)\/(\d+))/g);
    var lineHiddenFractions = ary[i] != null ? ary[i].replace(/([0-9]{1,})([\/]{1})([0-9]{1,})/g, "") : "";
    var numbersRegex = lineHiddenFractions.match(/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)/g);
    if (fractionsRegex !== null && fractionsRegex.length > 0) {
        // We have a fraction for this line.
        for (var j = 0; j < fractionsRegex.length; j++) {
            alert("Fraction on line " + i + ": " + fractionsRegex[j]);
        }
    }   
    if (numbersRegex !== null && numbersRegex.length > 0) {
        // We have a number for this line.
        for (var k = 0; k < numbersRegex.length; k++) {
            alert("Number on line " + i + ": " + numbersRegex[k]);
        }   
    }
}
```

I think this method offers you the most flexibility for what you want to do.  For each line, you will get an array of all of your fractions and an array of all of your numbers.  You can place booleans to check if the line has both numbers and fractions or just one or the other.  If you need to perform calculations, you can create formulas from the arrays of fractions and numbers from each line.

Comment: +1 I tested all suggestions and I ended up using this. My final function needs to be cleaned up and optimised, but it's currently doing what I wanted. Thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 1):

to calculate

```
function measure(string){
  var match = string.match(/^\d+(\s*\d*(\/+\d+))*/);
  if(match){
     match = match[0].split(" ");
     var m = 0;
     while(match.length){
        m += eval(match.shift());
     }
     return m;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

or to get the values separately

```
function get(string){
  var match = string.match(/^\d+(\s*\d*(\/+\d+))*/);
  if(match){
     match = match[0].split(" ");
     var m = 0;
     while(match.length){
        m += eval(match.shift());
     }
     return {integer:Math.floor(m), fraction:m-Math.floor(m)};
  }
  return {integer:0, fraction:0};
}
```

or to replace integer part and fraction part seperately

```
function replaceInteger(string, newInt){
  return string.replace(/^\d+\s+/, function(m, n){
     return newInt + " ";
  });
}

function replaceFraction(string, newFract){
  return string.replace(/^\d+\/+\d+\s+/, function(m, n){
     return newFract + " ";
  });
}

replaceInteger("10 mint leaves, fresh", "100");
replaceFraction("1/2 lime leaves, fresh", "1/3");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach will do what you need. Just call `getQuantity`, it will return an object which may or may not contain properties `number` and `fraction`. Then once you get the result, you can perform logic to determine what to do with it.

```
function getQuantity(recipe){
    var regex = /^(([1-9]+\d*\s)?((\d+)\/(\d+)\s)?).*$/g;
    var results = regex.exec(recipe);
    if(results[2] && results[5]){
         return {number: Number(results[2]), fraction: Number(results[4]) / Number(results[5])};
    } if(results[5]){
         return {fraction: Number(results[4]) / Number(results[5])};
    } else{
         return {number: Number(results[2])};
    }
 }

getQuantity("1 1/2 oz. white rum"); // {number: 1, fraction: 0.5}
getQuantity("1/2 lime, cut in 4 wedges"); // {fraction: 0.5}
getQuantity("10 mint leaves, fresh"); // {number: 10}
getQuantity("2 tbsp. white sugar"); // {number: 2}
getQuantity("1 cup ice cubes"); // {number: 1}
getQuantity("1/2 cup club soda"); // {fraction: 0.5}
```